# Make a method to return Execution Time of another Method

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I'm trying to come up with a method which will measure and return the execution time of another method. Basically something like this:

```
public void DoSomething(Int32 aNumber)
{ /* Stuff happens */ }

//
// Somewhere else in code:
TimeSpan executionTime = MyDiag.MeasureExecTime(DoSomething(5));

// Now executionTime contains how long DoSomething(5) took to execute,
// e.g. 2.55463 seconds.
```

How can I do this (the MeasureExecTime method)?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232848/wrapping-stopwatch-timing-with-a-delegate-or-lambda ?

Comment: How is this a duplicate to Jeff's question on measuring via lambda? And besides, I already accepted an answer to this question, too much time on your hands?

Comment: The fact that the accepted answer is almost identical to the accepted answer on the other question makes me wonder if it's a duplicate, that's all. No need to be snarky about it.

Comment: Might I ask why? If you're wanting to do some quick benchmarks, great; if you want to profile an application, use a profiler. There's a bare-bones free one at http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler and there are several full-featured commercial offerings (ANTS, dotTrace).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've just created such a method to test performance in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343934/fastest-way-to-implement-duplicate-character-removal-in-string-c):

```
private static TimeSpan MeasureExecTime(Action action, int iterations)
{
    action(); // warm up
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        action();
    }
    return sw.Elapsed;
}
```

Usage:

```
MeasureExecTime(() => DoSomething(5), 100000);
```

See *280Z28*'s answer if you don't want to test more than one iteration :-)

Comment: That was my question too. I actually got the idea to write this from your answer (w/ performance tests) in the other question. lol.

Comment: Your for loop adds overhead and may distort the results (although not significantly...). You should start the stopwatch before action(), and pause it after

Comment: @Thomas, it has a few flaws, but calling action before stopwatch startnew is not one of them. See my answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
public static TimeSpan MeasureExecTime(Action action)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    action();
    return stopwatch.Elapsed;
}
```