# Check string on duplicate char

Tags: c#, string, duplicates

first time I write on the SO, because he could not find solution myself.
At the interview, I was given the task to write a method that checks the characters in the string to a unique.

*Requirements*: **not using LINQ**. *Desirable*: do not use additional data types (Dictionary, HashSet...etc. Arrays and lists **Allowed**)

Example:

```
"Hello" - return false; "Helo" - return true
```

My implementation:

```
static HashSet<char> charSet = new HashSet<char>();

static bool IsUniqueChar(string str)
{       
    foreach (char c in str)
    {            
           charSet.Add(c);                         
    }
    return charSet.Count() == str.Length;
}
```

But it does not meet the requirements of data types, and is not the best performance...
I also tried the approach with a dictionary:

```
static Dictionary<char,bool> charSetDictionary = new Dictionary<char,bool>();

static bool IsUniqueChar(string str)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            charSetDictionary.Add(c,true);
        }
    }
    catch 
    {
        return false;
    }
```

But he is no better than the previous. 
I will welcome any idea how to solve this task better?
p.s

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    IsUniqueChar("Hello");

    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed={0}", sw.Elapsed); //~005044
}
```

Comment: have you check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1343953/1880431

Comment: what are the characters ? Are they only alphabets ? is A=='a'..?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most likely, your interviewer would like to see an approach using knowledge about Unicode:

```
static bool[] charsHash = new bool[512];

static bool IsUniqueChar(string str)
{
    if (str.Length > 512) return false;

    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        bool alreadyExist = charsHash[(int)c];
        if (alreadyExist) return false;
        else charsHash[(int)c] = !alreadyExist;
    }
    return true;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    IsUniqueChar("Hello");

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed={0}", sw.Elapsed);//~000283
}
```

Comment: This is the best way O(1) extra space and O(n) time complexity

Comment: From wiki: *the latest version of Unicode contains a repertoire of more than 110,000 characters covering 100 scripts.* It would require really big `charsHash` array to make it work with Unicode :)

Comment: @vikram I really dont understand why that is the case. If a char is 2 bytes, there are 65536 values, not 512. Could you or the OP explain?

Comment: Actually char represents a unicode character, using a variable length UTF16 encoding. It can be either 2 or 4 bytes, otherwise it wiuld not be able to represent more than 65536 characters. See wikipedia.

Comment: @Rotem silly me sorry u are right this is bit inefficient in c# (would have been sufficient in c as char has 1 byte in it)

Comment: -1. How is this solution "using knowledge about Unicode"? The algorithm crashes for strings containing any character with a codepoint larger than U+01FF (511).

Comment: @Rotem Actually, `char` represents a  UTF-16 code unit which is always 2 bytes large. For characters outside of the Basic Multilingual Plane (> U+10FFFF), 2 chars are used (see surrogate pairs)

Comment: @Rotem Correction (too late for editing): The BMP of course ends at U+FFFF, not U+10FFFF

Answer (score 8):

The fastest way uses `HashSet<char>`:

```
var set = new HashSet<char>();

foreach(var c in input)
{
    if(!set.Add(c))
        return false;
}

return true;
```

It's *O(n)* solution in worst case (input is unique). Returns `false` as soon as first duplicate is found.

Without `HashSet<char>` you can easily transform `string` to `char[]`, sort it and check if you have two consecutive items with the same value.

```
var chars = input.ToCharArray();
chars.Sort();

for(int i = 1; i < chars.Length; i++)
{
    if(chars[i-1] == chars[i])
        return false;
}

return true;
```

`Sort` is *O(n log(n))* and so is the entire function.

Comment: U are right that c# char has 2 bytes hence it is better to HashSet or sorting instead of boolean array +1 .

Answer (score 1):

All answers so far are based on the assumption that one .NET `char` corresponds to one Unicode *character*. This is only true for characters in the [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29). Characters outside the BMP are encoded using **two** `char` objects (*surrogate pair*).

The following code handles this special case:

```
HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    string s;
    if (char.IsHighSurrogate(str[i]))
    {
        s = str.Substring(i, 2);
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        s = str.Substring(i, 1);
    }

    if (!set.Add(s))
    {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the test string is passed through **textBox1**, then it follows:

```
string tst;
int i,j, stat =0;
tst = textBox1.Text;
for (i = 0; i < tst.Length; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < tst.Length; j++)
    {
        if ((tst[i] == tst[j]) && (i != j))
        {
            stat = 1;
            break;
        }
        else continue;
    }
    if (stat == 1) break;
    else continue;
}
if (stat == 1) MessageBox.Show("False");
else MessageBox.Show("True");
```

***Every string is an array of characters.***

Comment: inefficient O(n^2) can do better than that.

Comment: @Vikram: Yes, you're right. I didn't mention efficiency in my code. No doubt it's best and worst cases are way too far, but for the purpose, it's ok.

Comment: Isn't this always producing `false` guys, for any string? If you allow i to be equal to j, `arr[i] == arr[j]` is always true at this point... Which is the case in the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: @t_over : Yes. You're right. I've made the edit. Thanx.